# text file to 2d arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, text

I have had a look at other posts, but I am still stuck on this issue for a while now. I have a text file that has various new lines, each of different length. I want to store them in a 2d array so that I can call specific locations i.e. word[1][4].

I've managed to store them in an array - my code is below. Thanks for your help!

```
String line = null;
ClassToRead txtFile = new ClassToRead("test.txt"); //reading using bufferReader
String [][] words = new String[txtFile.readLines()][]; //this is where I want to store the words

while( (line = br.readLine())!= null ){

     String [] newData = line.split("\\s+");

  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newData)); //prints out array

}

//I want to use specific locations in the 2d array e.g. System.out.println(words[3][5]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the arrays to the 2d array... you could use a counter like in the example bellow.

```
int counter = 0;
while( (line = br.readLine())!= null ){
    String[] newData = line.split("\\s+");
    words[counter] = newData;
    counter++;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newData)); //prints out array
}
```

Comment: You are a star!! I didn't think about having a counter, thanks a lot!